# How to properly free a malloc'd structure?

Tags: c, malloc, free

Let's say I have a malloc'd struct with certain fields:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    int integer;
    char* array;
    ...
    }
```

I malloc an array of this structs but, when I want to free them, should I just:

```
/* Loop */
free(myStruct[i])
myStruct[i] = NULL

free(myStruct)
```

Or should I free every field of the structure, and then the struct itself?

Comment: anything that was malloced needs to be freed

Comment: Do you mean `free(myStruct.array[i])`? Or `free(myStructArray[i].array)`? Please post actual code.

Comment: You basically have to free a pointer that was returned by `malloc()`. That's it.

Comment: yeah i mean that, free every field, then the struct itself

Comment: Not free every field (I hope you're not thinking about freeing `integer`). Free every pointer that was ever returned by  malloc.

Comment: Please provide more complete code, like for excample what is `myStruct[i]`? How do you allocate? Can you please edit your question to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 4):

If you call malloc like this:

`myStruct *s = malloc(sizeof(myStruct ));`

then you should call free on whatever pointer was returned from malloc (in this case called `s`):

`free(s);`

The same thing goes if you call malloc like this:

`myStruct *s = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) * NUM_IN_ARRAY);
//...
free(s);`

Although, if you previously assigned a malloc'd pointer to a char* field in the structure, remember you need to free that as well.

Answer (score 3):

If your `char* array` values were individually `malloc`ed, you need to loop over each element of the `struct` array and free them first - otherwise you end up with "unreachable" memory and thus a leak.

The only time this doesn't really matter is at termination of a program - anything you didn't clean up will be done for you.

Possible code sample:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  int integer;
  char* array;
  ...
}

myStruct* A;
int N;
A = malloc(N * sizeof *A);
for(int ii=0; ii<N; ii++) A[ii].array = malloc(20);
```

Now if you did

```
free(A); A=NULL;   // ****** BAD - DON'T DO IT ******
```

You would end up with a memory leak. Instead you will need to loop over each element, and free the array inside the struct:

```
for(int ii=0; ii<N; ii++) {
  free(A[ii].array);
  A[ii].array=NULL;
}
free(A); A=NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should free what you mallocated.

So for each malloc (or strdup) you should have one and only one matching free.

Comment: Initially I just said 'You should free what you mallocated' and maybe they thought it was a bit short :(

Comment: just like wall street..few downvotes and the cookie crumbles.. :P